# PHP Regex for .vtt files

Tags: php, regex, webvtt

I am looking to loop through existing .vtt files and read the cue data into a database.

The format of the .vtt files are:

```
WEBVTT FILE

line1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000
‘Stuff’

line2
00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:20.000
Other stuff
Example with 2 lines

line3
00:00:20.00 --> 00:00:30.000
Example with only 2 digits in milliseconds

line4
00:00:30.000 --> 00:00:40.000
Different stuff

00:00:40.000 --> 00:00:50.000
Example without a head line
```

Originally I was trying to use `^` and `$` to be quite regimented with the lines along the lines of: `/^(\w*)$^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3}) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3})$^(.+)$/ims` but I struggled to get this working in the regex checker and resorted to using `\s` to deal with line start/ends.

Currently I am using the following regex: `/(.*)\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3}) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3})\s(.+)/im`

This partially works using online regex checkers like: https://regex101.com/r/mmpObk/3 (this example does not pick up multi-line subtitles, but does get the first line which at this point is good enough for my purpose as all subtitles are currently 1 liners). However if I put this into php (`preg_match_all("/(.*)\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3}) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3})\s(.+)/mi", $fileData, $matches)`) and dump the results I get an array of empty arrays.

What might be different between the online regex and php?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT---
Below is a dump of $fileData and a dump of $matches:

```
string(341) "WEBVTT FILE

line1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000
‘Stuff’

line2
00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:20.000
Other stuff
Example with 2 lines

line3
00:00:20.00 --> 00:00:30.000
Example with only 2 digits in milliseconds

line4
00:00:30.000 --> 00:00:40.000
Different stuff

00:00:40.000 --> 00:00:50.000
Example without a head line"

array(11) {
    [0]=>
        array(0) {}
    [1]=>
        array(0) {}
    [2]=>
        array(0) {}
    [3]=>
        array(0) {}
    [4]=>
        array(0) {}
    [5]=>
        array(0) {}
    [6]=>
        array(0) {}
    [7]=>
        array(0) {}
    [8]=>
        array(0) {}
    [9]=>
        array(0) {}
    [10]=>
        array(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Is all that data in the variable `$fileData`? So you don't get these matches: https://3v4l.org/3CqC7

Comment: I dumped out the content of $fileData and everything looks correct to me - I have added the dumps to the original question for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is poor line-ending handling.

You have this at the end: `\s(.+)/mi`.
This only matches 1 whitespace, but newlines can be 1 or 2 whitespaces.

To fix it, you can use `\R(.+)/mi`.

It works on the website because it is normalizing your newlines into Linux-style newlines.
That is, Windows-style newlines are `\r\n` (2 characters) and Linux-style are `\n` (1 character).

---

Alternativelly, you can try this regular expression:

```
/(?:line(\d+)\R)?(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\R((?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n[^\r\n])*)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)/i
```

It looks horrible, but it works.
Note: I'm swapping between `\R` and `\r\n` because `\R` matches the literal `R` inside `[]`.

The data is captured like this:

1. Line number (if present)
2. Initial timestamp
3. Final timestamp
4. Multiline text

You can try it on https://regex101.com/r/Yk8iD1/1

You can use the handy code generator tool to generate the following PHP:

```
$re = '/(?:line(\d+)\R)?(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\R((?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n[^\r\n])*)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)/i';
$str = 'WEBVTT FILE

line1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000
‘Stuff’

line2
00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:20.000
Other stuff
Example with 2 lines

line3
00:00:20.00 --> 00:00:30.000
Example with only 2 digits in milliseconds

line4
00:00:30.000 --> 00:00:40.000
Different stuff

00:00:40.000 --> 00:00:50.000
Example without a head line';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

You can test it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f5362f56e912f3504ed075e7013071059cdee7b

Comment: `/(?:line(\d+)\R)?(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\R((?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n[^\r\n])*)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)/i` worked perfectly - thanks also for the explanation

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the feedback. While I'm happy that you've accepted my answer, I always advise to wait 1-2 days before accepting, in case someone makes another answer.

Comment: I restored my intended captures as follows: `/(?:(\w+)\R)?(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2,3})\R((?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n[^\r\n])*)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)/i`

Comment: Do you want me to fix the answer? I would have to re-do the examples and stuff.

Comment: I don't know what the SO protocol is - I had presumed that my comment above with the regex I am using would be enough for people to find and reference.

Answer (score 0):

Vtt file can have differently formated timestamps, styles, user errors... If you want to reliably parse the file the more robust solution would be to use a library:

```
$data = Subtitle::loadFromString($vtt)->getInternalFormat();
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 0.0
            [end] => 10.0
            [lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ‘Stuff’
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10.0
            [end] => 20.0
            [lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Other stuff
                    [1] => Example with 2 lines
                )
        )
)
```

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles